# Emacs packages not loaded when adding to configuration.nix

Tags: emacs, nixos

I am following the documentation on https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/ to add packages to emacs. I installed emacs with `nix-env -i emacs.` As it describes I created a file called emacs.nix

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
let
    myEmacs = pkgs.emacs;
    emacsWithPackages = (pkgs.emacsPackagesNgGen myEmacs).emacsWithPackages;
in
    emacsWithPackages (
        epkgs:  (with epkgs.melpaStablePackages; [
            magit
            labburn-theme
            cider
            company
            flycheck
            iedit
            yasnippet
            nix-mode
] )
)
```

And then run `nix-build emacs.nix`. After that I had a result symlink, as expected. Finally, I confirmed that my packages are working by running emacs with `./result/bin/emacs`, run `package-initialized` and finally checked that the extensions are working.

Now the problem is after I try to add it to my global configuration. As suggested I added the following to my configuration.nix file:

```
{
 environment.systemPackages = [
   # [...]
   (import ./emacs.nix { inherit pkgs; })
  ];
}
```

I run `nixos-rebuild switch`. This procedure doesn't give access to the packages on emacs.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem. Make sure you remove vanilla "pkgs.emacs" from your environment.systemPackages list. Once that is done it worked as expected for me.